# Does Vimeo have an open starder for developing Upload Links? If yes, where can I find them?

Tags: upload, dropbox-api, vimeo-api

I am building a routine to take the output of the Dropbox Temporary Upload Link produced using the Dropbox API and load it into the Vimeo API Upload POST call in the upload.link parameter.  I have managed to get the Dropbox API to spit out the temporary Upload links but when I put the link into the TRY IT API tester on the Vimeo developer website (see response below).  This is a positive response and the video shows up in the Vimeo library but it never finishs transcoding.

I just was told by Dropbox that Vimeo has changed things so that their upload links are no longer accepted by Vimeo's upload API endpoint. So am trying to figure out if:

A.) what Dropbox is telling me is true
2.) if Vimeo has open standards for writing upload links that I could use to develop a solution using S3 for example

===============================================
Vimeo API response to POST: [https://api.vimeo.com/users/{user_id}/videos](https://api.vimeo.com/users/%7Buser_id%7D/videos) on the Try It App on the Vimeo developer website.

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/vnd.vimeo.video+json
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 50
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 28
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 2023-11-28T23:12:29+00:00

{
"uri": "/videos/889297979",
"name": "press-master",
"description": "Video to test upload",
"type": "video",
"link": "https://vimeo.com/889297979",
"player_embed_url": "https://player.vimeo.com/video/889297979?h=abe97d3e69",
"duration": 0,
"width": 400,
"language": null,
"height": 300,
"embed": {

Things that I have tried.

1.)Three different videos from three different sources - all MP4.  None work.
2.) Running the API on the Vimeo Website App and from my own app.  Responses are both positive.
3.) reaching out to Vimeo - not holding my breath.

Vimeo is a billion dollar company so I had assumed that while i had heard their API was a pain in the ass, that once you figured it out, it would work.  **Do any of your do automated uploads to Vimeo using their API?  **

If anyone has suggestions for developing temporary links that don't cause indigestion for Vimeo, please share this with me and tell me what platform you have used this on.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Cheers,

ON

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Uploading-Videos-to-Vimeo/td-p/733139 ]